# Use sseclient inside python web server

Tags: python, webserver, fastapi, server-sent-events

I would like to use python module [sseclient](https://pypi.org/project/sseclient/) in order to listen SSE streams, but I want to use it inside a python web server built with FastAPI.

The problem here is that sseclient consumes from the SSE event stream in a blocking way, so my python server would become inaccesible.

I wonder what is the best practice to achive something like this.

Should I use a separate thread?

Could the use of async/await help here?

Could the use of Server Workers provide any help to that issue?

Should I use a totally different service for the sse client, outside my python web server?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you want to do with the events received from sseclient while it runs? An option is to either run it out of process and integrate it through the API with something like Redis, run it in a separate thread (.. but where to store the events) or find another optional library to use that supports async/await instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the reply. With the received sse events, I want to update a database that is connected with my web server. As you said, I guess that I would use a async/await implementation. But what if I want to listen to many streams? Is it preferable all that functionality to be out of the server process?

Comment: That really sounds like something that should live outside of the API server process yes; if you don't have a library that allows you to follow many streams in the same process, you'll have to spawn a separate process / worker for each stream you want to follow.